# Multi-level Subdomains in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wildcard-subdomain

Can we have multi-level subdomain in Rails like this?

```
sub1.sub2.mysite.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check the subdomain the app is accessed from using **request.subdomains**

But if you are going to do something more advanced you should probably use 
[subdomain-fu](http://github.com/mbleigh/subdomain-fu/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason why you couldn't have a subdomain of a subdomain being used in a rails app.

You'll want to setup a wildcard A record in your domain DNS and configure your http server to accept wildcard server aliases.

Then in your application_controller you'll probably want a before_filter that does some juju with

```
request.host
```

to do whatever you want, be it

`Account.find_by_domain(parsed_request_host)` or whatever.

Comment: Roger/Mark, thanks for the reply.

Well, now it clear to me that we can achieve multi-level sub-domains.

Let me proceed a bit further with my actual requirement. 

In my Rails application a user can have multiple categories and then multiple items associated with one category. Consider the following scenario:

Domain:site.com

Group:G1
  Items:i1,i2

Group:G2
  Items: i1,i2

Now,the requirement is to have a different URL for each item. Considering the above data we'll have following URLs:

http://i1.G1.site.com
http://i2.G1.site.com
http://i1.G2.site.com
http://i2.G2.site.com

Please advise.